# Flex: Does data binding work with the UITextField?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, uitextfield

Does data binding work with the UITextField? Unfortunately, I'm getting the variable instead of the bound data.

```
[Bindable]
public var myString:String;
```

in a function, where tf is a UITextField:

myString = "blah blah blah";
blah blah...

```
tf.text="{myString}";
```

It's giving me {myString} instead of its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. It turned out that I didn't need the "{}". It works if I use:

`tf.text= myString;`